# Did Vincent Van Gogh say "If you truly love nature, you will find beauty everywhere”?

Tags: quotes

I came upon this quote on p. 88 of National Geographic's  [*Sublime Nature: Photographs That Awe and Inspire*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1426213018).

[If You Truly Love Nature... | Empress of Dirt](https://empressofdirt.net/love-nature/)

> November 26, 2014 ♛ By [Melissa J. Will](https://empressofdirt.net/author/melissajwill/)
>
> If you truly love nature, you will find beauty everywhere. ~Vincent Van Gogh
>
> ### Deeds and Words
>
> **“If you truly love nature, you will find beauty everywhere.”**
>
> This quote has been floating around for years. I have no idea if Van Gogh actually said or wrote it, but the sentiment still holds.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Yes, this is a real quote by Vincent van Gogh (although translated).**

It is included in the [page for Vincent van Gogh on Wikiquote](https://en.m.wikiquote.org/wiki/Vincent_van_Gogh), which is generally a good resource for verifying (alleged) quotes.

As found on Wikiquote, the quote was written by Vincent van Gogh in a letter to his brother, know as 'Letter 22'.
The full letter is [available online](http://vangoghletters.org/vg/letters/let022/letter.html), including facsimile, transcription, and translation.

The letter was written in Dutch, so the quote as posted in the question is a translation of the original, which is as follows:

> Als men waarachtig van de natuur houdt dan vindt men ’t overal mooi.